# Package WinForms (Desktop App) and GameBar App in one Microsoft Store App

Tags: uwp, desktop-bridge

Since GameBar Widgets are also UWP Apps, I thought it would be very easy to package my Desktop App with the GameBar Widget. Basically I want my users to do certain things in the Desktop App that affect the GameBar widget. When I actually made the submission I noticed that the GameBar widget actually never got deployed.

I followed all of the steps here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-extend

Am I out of luck here or did I forget to do something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could not package the Game Bar widget app with the desktop app. You should upload the Game Bar widget app directly to the store and search it in the Xbox Game Bar's widget store. This is the correct way to distribute the Game Bar widget app.

Comment: Thanks Roy! I went along and split these two up. If you have a moment, could you please check out my latest question as I think there might have been a bug introduced via the latest version of the Game Bar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64673315/how-do-i-make-an-xbox-game-bar-widget-transparent-while-game-bar-is-visible